# Is the structure of my C# code and my way of thinking right?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm a first year student at a college that focuses heavily on self learning (SCRUM) without any classical lessons.
Because of this, I basically learned everything I know from websites like this.
I don't wan't to get any bad habits or wrong understandings.
So, is this code any good?
I'm not looking for optimization (wouldn't mind any tips though ;) ) since I'll be learning that through time, but rather if the general structure and my way of thinking is right.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string repeat;
    //do while loop for if the user wants to run the program again
    do
    {
        //asigns variables
        string text;
        int vowels, consonants, numbers, otherSymbols;
        var hsVowels = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
        var hsConsonants = new HashSet<char> { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
        var hsNumbers = new HashSet<char> { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

        //asks for input
        Console.WriteLine("Input anything and the program wil tell you how many vowels, consonants, numbers and other symbols you gave.");
        text = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        //calculates
        vowels = text.Count(c => hsVowels.Contains(c));
        consonants = text.Count(c => hsConsonants.Contains(c));
        numbers = text.Count(c => hsNumbers.Contains(c));
        otherSymbols = text.Length - (vowels + consonants + numbers);

        //shows the result
        Console.WriteLine("Your input has {0} vowels, {1} consonants, {2} numbers and {3} other Symbols.", vowels, consonants, numbers, otherSymbols);

        //asks if the user wants to run the program again
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to try again? (yes/no)");
        repeat = Console.ReadLine();
        //tests if the users input was valid (yes/no)
        while (!(repeat.ToLower().Contains("yes") || repeat.ToLower().Contains("no")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Invalid input. Please answer ""yes"" or ""no"" .");
            repeat = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    } while (repeat.ToLower().Contains("yes"));
}
```

I somehow didn't manage to make the code sample recognize my code as C#.
If anyone could tell me how, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Although you might get some responses here, Stack Exchange has a site specifically for this, where you will probably get a better result: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @sellotape Thanks for the recommendation! I will do that once the 40 minute cool down is over. Should I delete this question or leave it up for if someone does respond?

Comment: I would probably delete it - people can always respond on the new one.

Comment: You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. The answer of Alex might help others as well so I guess it's alright...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the code and it works. So good job :-)

As sellotape suggested it might be a good idea- to post in the suggested site.

Having said that here are some changes I have made to your code to make it more readable, and to reduce some repetition:

use a while loop and set your condition variable before you enter the loop. You will do at least one cycle:

```
        string repeat = "yes";
        //Main loop
        while (repeat.Contains("yes"))
```

One line variable declaration. I personally don't advise it. It makes it easier to read by declaring one variable at the time in a single line:

```
    string inputText;
    int howManyVowels;
    int howManyConsonants;
    int howManynumbers;
    int howManySymbols;
```

From above you can see that I have tried to be as explicit as possible with my naming. Don't be afraid to be verbose when naming. A well named variable is self explanatory and shows intend.

The use of var. There are so many opinions about it. In writing good code , I personally think that var must be used as less as possible. In this case would be ok as the right hand side is self explanatory. However it would be better to show the left hand side type.

```
List<char> listOfVowels = new List<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
```

This is just my preference. The use of List instead of HashSet. As we are not really concern with performance- in this case- the use of List highlights the fact that we are dealing with a list of char.

Last point, if you need to check for a lower case response , then set the repeat variable ToLower() when you initialize it:

```
repeat = Console.ReadLine().ToLower()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering in so much depth! I definitely learned some important basics about good programming.